# Deadlock vs "Progress" requirement of the solution to the critical section problem

Tags: operating-systems, deadlocks, critical-section

I came across following problem:

> Consider following code:
>
> ```
> () 
> {  
>     [] = ;  
>     ([]);  
>     /*   */  
>     [] = ;  
>     /*  */  
> }
> ```
>
> Let flag is declared as Boolean `flag[2]` and `Pi` denote one process while `Pj` denotes other process and `i=1-j`. Both processes execute concurrently, then does the progress requirement of the solution to the critical section problem satisfied in the above case?

**Doubt**

The solution says that both processes Pi and Pj can simultaneously execute `flag[i]=true` and then both may busy wait on `while(flag[j])`, thus leading to deadlock and hence progress requirement of the solution to the critical section problem is not satisfied.

I know the normal / day to day meaning of "progress" gives us feeling that if there can be deadlock, then there may not be the progress. But Galvin's book defines "Progress" as this:

> If no process is executing in its critical section and some processes
>   wish to enter their critical sections, then only those processes that
>   are not executing in their remainder sections can participate in
>   deciding which will enter its critical section next, and this
>   selection cannot be postponed indefinitely.

So I am guessing whether progress has anything to do with deadlock. And whether the code indeed satisfies progress requirement of critical section problem.

Answer (score 1):

> and this selection cannot be postponed indefinitely

In case of deadlock, deciding which process will enter next will be postponed indefinitely. So progress won't happen.